# MFMailComposeResult constants don't compile in Swift 2.3

Tags: swift, email, swift2

I updated to XCode 8 this morning and chose to convert my Swift files to 2.3 rather than 3. I have resolved all of my compilation issues, except for the code below. Only the MFMailComposeResultSent case actually does anything important. XCode says MFMailComposeResultSent and the other similar cases are unresolved identifiers. The latest documentation shows I should be using MFMailComposeResult.sent, and the auto-suggest feature offers this as a possibility, but it also refuses to compile. I'd be grateful for info on how to make this compile for use with Swift 2.3.

Thanks.

```
func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail canceled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        makeToast("Successfully sent email.", duration: 3)
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    default:
        break
    }
    hideActivityIndicator()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is with the `rawValue` everywhere? Just switch on the cases. Like this:

```
switch result {
case .Cancelled: // something
case .Saved: // something
// .. and so on
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this with the ".sent" and ".failed" that the documentation shows, but it didn't work I guess because that documentation is for Swift 3. Your approach solved the problem.

Comment: Well, of course this in turn raises the question of why on earth you would elect to use an outdated version of Swift. You have made things _much_ more difficult for yourself. Why?

Comment: I will transition to 3, but need to go more gradually, since some of the previous version conversions have been severe enough to cost a whole day of work, which I can't afford at the moment.

Comment: And what you're going through with stuff like this example is "less" work?